# C# Regex Split but include empty string if fails to split

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, formatting

I am trying to split a string into an array of strings. 
My current string looks like this and this is all in one string. It also has newlines (\r\n) and spaces. I put a better-looking example here.

---

```
BFFPPB14     Dark Chocolate Dried Cherries     14 oz (397g)

INGREDIENTS: DARK CHOCOLATE (SUGAR, CHOCOLATE LIQUOR, COCOA BUTTER,
ANHYDROUS MILK FAT, SOYA LECITHIN, VANILLIN [AN ARTIFICIAL FLAVOR]), DRIED 
TART CHERRIES (CHERRIES, SUGAR), GUM ARABIC, CONFECTIONER'S GLAZE.

CONTAINS: MILK, SOY

ALLERGEN INFORMATION: MAY CONTAIN TREE NUTS, PEANUTS, EGG AND 
WHEAT. 

01/11/2019

Description: Sweetened dried Montmorency cherries that are panned with dark chocolate. 

Storage Conditions: Store at ambient temperatures with a humidity less than 50%. 
Shelf Life: 9 months

Company Name

Item No.: 701804

Bulk: 415265

Supplier: Cherryland's Best

WARNING: CHERRIES MAY CONTAIN PITS
```

---

My Regex looks like this

```
List<string> result = Regex.Split(text, @"INGREDIENTS: |CONTAINS: |ALLERGEN INFORMATION: |(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})|Description: |Storage Conditions: |Shelf Life: |Company Name|Item No.: |Bulk: |Supplier: |WARNING: ").ToList();
```

[This is what result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PUNX.png)

Note: The first string is the product name

Sometimes I get strings that don't have a supplier or a warning, I want the split to have empty strings if it doesn't find that split value.

EX:

```
result[0] = "blabla"
result[1] = ""
result[2] = "blabla"
```

That way I know that result 1 was split on the value (INGREDIENTS: ) and I can assign it to something

Answer (score 0):

### So if your requirement is :

- find a line with starting with with specif word

### use Linq

### use StartsWith

### code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // test string

            var str = @"BFFPPB10 Dark Chocolate Macadamia Nuts 11 oz (312g)\r\nINGREDIENTS: DARK CHOCOLATE (SUGAR, CHOCOLATE, COCOA BUTTER, \r\nANHYDROUS MILK FAT, SOY LECITHIN, VANILLA), MACADAMIA NUTS, SEA SALT.\r\nCONTAINS: MACADAMIA NUTS, MILK, SOY.\r\nALLERGEN INFORMATION: MAY CONTAIN OTHER TREE NUTS, PEANUTS, EGG AND\r\nWHEAT.\r\n01/11/2019\r\nDescription: Dry roasted, salted macadamias covered in dark chocolate.\r\nStorage Conditions: Store at ambient temperatures with a humidity less than 50%. \r\nShelf Life: 12 months\r\nBlain's Farm & Fleet\r\nItem No.: 701772\r\nBulk: 421172\r\nSupplier: Devon's\r\n";

            // Keys

            const string KEY_INGREDIENTS = "INGREDIENTS:";
            const string KEY_CONTAINS = "CONTAINS:";
            const string KEY_ALLERGEN_INFORMATION = "ALLERGEN INFORMATION:";
            const string KEY_DESCRPTION = "Description:";
            const string KEY_STORAGE_CONDITION = "Storage Conditions:";
            const string KEY_SHELFLIFE = "Shelf Life:";
            const string KEY_ITEM_NO = "Item No.:";
            const string KEY_BULK = "Bulk:";
            const string KEY_SUPPLIER = "Supplier:";
            const string KEY_WARNING = "WARNING:";
            const string KEY_YEAR_Regex = @"^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$";
            const string KEY_AFTER_COMPANY_NAME = KEY_ITEM_NO;


            // Helpers

            var keys = new string[]
            { KEY_INGREDIENTS, KEY_CONTAINS, KEY_ALLERGEN_INFORMATION, KEY_DESCRPTION, KEY_STORAGE_CONDITION,
                KEY_SHELFLIFE, KEY_ITEM_NO, KEY_BULK, KEY_SUPPLIER, KEY_WARNING };

            var lines = str.Split(new string[] { @"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            void log(string key, string val)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{key} =>  {val}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            void removeLine(string line)
            {
                if (line != null) lines = lines.Where(w => w != line).ToArray();
            }


            // get Multi Line Item with key

            string getMultiLine(string key)
            {
                var line = lines
                            .Select((linetxt, index) => new { linetxt, index })
                                .Where(w => w.linetxt.StartsWith(key))
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                if (line == null) return string.Empty;

                var result = line.linetxt;

                for (int i = line.index + 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!keys.Any(a => lines[i].StartsWith(a)))
                        result += lines[i];
                    else
                        break;
                }

                return result;
            }


            // get single Line Item before spesic key if the Line is not a key

            string getLinebefore(string the_after_key)
            {
                var the_after_line = lines
                            .Select((linetxt, index) => new { linetxt, index })
                                .Where(w => w.linetxt.StartsWith(the_after_key))
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                if (the_after_line == null) return string.Empty;

                var the_before_line_text = lines[the_after_line.index - 1];

                //not a key
                if (!keys.Any(a => the_before_line_text.StartsWith(a)))
                    return the_before_line_text;
                else
                    return null;
            }



            // 1st get item without key

            var itemName = lines.FirstOrDefault();
            removeLine(itemName);

            var year = lines.Where(w => Regex.Match(w, KEY_YEAR_Regex).Success).FirstOrDefault();
            removeLine(year);

            var companyName = getLinebefore(KEY_AFTER_COMPANY_NAME);
            removeLine(companyName);

            //2nd get item with Keys

            var ingredients = getMultiLine(KEY_INGREDIENTS);
            var contanins = getMultiLine(KEY_CONTAINS);
            var allergenInfromation = getMultiLine(KEY_ALLERGEN_INFORMATION);
            var description = getMultiLine(KEY_DESCRPTION);
            var storageConditions = getMultiLine(KEY_STORAGE_CONDITION);
            var shelfLife = getMultiLine(KEY_SHELFLIFE);
            var itemNo = getMultiLine(KEY_ITEM_NO);
            var bulk = getMultiLine(KEY_BULK);
            var supplier = getMultiLine(KEY_SUPPLIER);
            var warning = getMultiLine(KEY_WARNING);


            // 3rd log

            log("ItemName", itemName);
            log("Ingredients", ingredients);
            log("contanins", contanins);
            log("Allergen Infromation", allergenInfromation);
            log("Year", year);
            log("Description", description);
            log("Storage Conditions", storageConditions);
            log("Shelf Life", shelfLife);
            log("CompanyName", companyName);
            log("Item No", itemNo);
            log("Bulk", bulk);
            log("Supplier", supplier);
            log("warning", warning);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
}
```

will output

> ItemName =>  BFFPPB10 Dark Chocolate Macadamia Nuts 11 oz (312g)
>
> Ingredients =>  INGREDIENTS: DARK CHOCOLATE (SUGAR, CHOCOLATE, COCOA
>   BUTTER, ANHYDROUS MILK FAT, SOY LECITHIN, VANILLA), MACADAMIA NUTS,
>   SEA SALT.
>
> contanins =>  CONTAINS: MACADAMIA NUTS, MILK, SOY.
>
> Allergen Infromation =>  ALLERGEN INFORMATION: MAY CONTAIN OTHER TREE
>   NUTS, PEANUTS, EGG ANDWHEAT.
>
> Year =>  01/11/2019
>
> Description =>  Description: Dry roasted, salted macadamias covered in
>   dark chocolate.
>
> Storage Conditions =>  Storage Conditions: Store at ambient
>   temperatures with a humidity less than 50%.
>
> Shelf Life =>  Shelf Life: 12 months
>
> CompanyName =>  Blain's Farm & Fleet
>
> Item No =>  Item No.: 701772
>
> Bulk =>  Bulk: 421172
>
> Supplier =>  Supplier: Devon's
>
> warning =>

Comment: I am sorry. But this is what the string actually looks like

Comment: "BFFPPB10   Dark Chocolate Macadamia Nuts   11 oz (312g)\r\nINGREDIENTS: DARK CHOCOLATE (SUGAR, CHOCOLATE, COCOA BUTTER, \r\nANHYDROUS MILK FAT, SOY LECITHIN, VANILLA), MACADAMIA NUTS, SEA SALT.\r\nCONTAINS: MACADAMIA NUTS, MILK, SOY.\r\nALLERGEN INFORMATION: MAY CONTAIN OTHER TREE NUTS, PEANUTS, EGG AND\r\nWHEAT.\r\n01/11/2019\r\nDescription: Dry roasted, salted macadamias covered in dark chocolate.\r\nStorage Conditions: Store at ambient temperatures with a humidity less than 50%. \r\nShelf Life: 12 months\r\nBlain's Farm & Fleet\r\nItem No.: 701772\r\nBulk: 421172\r\nSupplier: Devon's\r\n"

Comment: So if the string of some category is really long it will have new lines in it. And you can't really split it on new lines

Comment: Yes, but  ANHYDROUS MILK FAT, SOY LECITHIN, VANILLA), MACADAMIA NUTS, SEA SALT. is part of Ingredients

Comment: Thank you so much, this saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex may have performance concerns if you are using this in a high volume application.  Below is one possible regex you could use.  It is somewhat difficult to parse the product line and the "company name" line since it wasn't clear if the product code had a pattern and the company name line didn't have a ':' like the other fields, so the regex is somewhat "hacky" in those areas:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

namespace so20190113_01 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string text =
@"BFFPPB14 Dark Chocolate Dried Cherries 14 oz (397g)
INGREDIENTS: DARK CHOCOLATE (SUGAR, CHOCOLATE LIQUOR, COCOA BUTTER, ANHYDROUS MILK FAT, SOYA LECITHIN, VANILLIN [AN ARTIFICIAL FLAVOR]), DRIED TART CHERRIES (CHERRIES, SUGAR), GUM ARABIC, CONFECTIONER'S GLAZE.
CONTAINS: MILK, SOY
ALLERGEN INFORMATION: MAY CONTAIN TREE NUTS, PEANUTS, EGG AND WHEAT. 
01/11/2019
Description: Sweetened dried Montmorency cherries that are panned with dark chocolate. 
Storage Conditions: Store at ambient temperatures with a humidity less than 50%. Shelf Life: 9 months
Company Name
Item No.: 701804
Bulk: 415265
Supplier: Cherryland's Best
WARNING: CHERRIES MAY CONTAIN PITS";

            string pat =
                @"^\s*(?<product>\w+\s+\w+\s+\w*[^:]+)$
                |^ingredients:\s*(?<ingredients>.*)$
                |^contains:\s*(?<contains>.*)$
                |^allergen\s+information:\s*(?<allergen>.*)$
                |^(?<date>(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}))$
                |^description:\s*(?<description>.*)$
                |^storage\sconditions:\s*(?<storage>.*)$
                |^shelf\slife:\s*(?<shelf>.*)$
                |^company\sname\s*(?<company>.*)$
                |^item\sno\.:\s*(?<item>.*)$
                |^bulk:\s*(?<bulk>.*)$
                |^supplier:\s*(?<supplier>.*)$
                |^warning:\s*(?<warning>.*)$
                ";

            Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);

            // Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
            Match m = r.Match(text); // you might want to use the overload that supports a timeout value
            Console.WriteLine("Start---");
            while (m.Success) {
                foreach (Group g in m.Groups.Where(x => x.Success)) {
                    switch (g.Name) {
                    case "product":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Product({g.Success}): '{g.Value.Trim()}'");
                        break;
                    case "ingredients":
                        Console.WriteLine($"Ingredients({g.Success}): '{g.Value.Trim()}'");
                    break;
                    // etc.
                    }
                }
                m = m.NextMatch();
                }

            Console.WriteLine("End---");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a parser is the only way. Originally, I tried using this regex:

```
^([\w \.]+?):([\s\S]+?)(?=((^[\w \.]+?):))
```

The key component there is the look-ahead `?=` which allows the string to match all text from label to label. However, it doesn't work on the final line item since it does not precede another label and I could not find a regex that stops matching at a pattern that may not exist. If that regex exists, you can do it all in one line of code:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string>[] kvs = null;

//one line of code if the look-ahead would also consider non-existent matches
kvs = Regex.Matches(text, @"^([\w \.]+?):([\s\S]+?)(?=((^[\w \.]+?):))", RegexOptions.Multiline)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Groups[1].Value, x.Groups[2].Value.Trim(' ', '\r', '\n', '\t')))
    .ToArray();
```

This code does it well enough. Also, the document is not formatted consistently in that `Company Name` does not precede a colon. This is the only anchor pattern that will work since various lines are broken by new lines.

```
KeyValuePair<string, string>[] kvs = null;

//Otherwise, you have to write a parser
//get all start indexes of labels
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"^.+?:", RegexOptions.Multiline).Cast<Match>().ToArray();

kvs = new KeyValuePair<string, string>[matches.Length];

KeyValuePair<string, string> GetKeyValuePair(Match match1, int match1EndIndex)
{
    //get the label
    var label = text.Substring(match1.Index, match1.Value.Length - 1);

    //get the desc and trim white space
    var descStart = match1.Index + match1.Value.Length + 1;
    var desc = text
        .Substring(descStart, match1EndIndex - descStart)
        .Trim(' ', '\r', '\n', '\t');

    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(label, desc);
}

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Length - 1; i++)
{
    kvs[i] = GetKeyValuePair(matches[i], matches[i + 1].Index);
}

kvs[kvs.Length - 1] = GetKeyValuePair(matches[matches.Length - 1], text.Length);

foreach (var kv in kvs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key}: {kv.Value}");
}
```